# Creating button on Python AddIn toolbar to run python script when clicked?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I need to create a button on toolbar of arcgis 10.2 who run a python 2.7 script created before when I click. Then I need to know if it's possible in this button that script write results to an excel file.
To create a button I went to: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/creating-an-add-in-button.htm an I had follow steps, but I didn't know if this resulted... In these steps I never mentioned the document or the folder where I want this button will appear..

Comment: This is certainly possible. What happens when you run your tool?  What does your test code look like?